# Overlay consumes all touch events

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app puts an invisible overlay on the left edge of the screen, and if the user swipes **from the bottom half**, I want to catch this event and do something with it. The problem is that instead of only the bottom half, all touch events on the upper half of the edge (which is 8dp wide) are also consumed and thus not passed to the app underneath it.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLauncher"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparentblack80"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <be.robinj.ubuntu.unity.launcher.AppLauncher
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:icon="@drawable/launcher_bfb"
            custom:special="true"
            android:onClick="lalBfb_clicked"
            android:id="@+id/lalBfb"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:tag="partOfLauncher" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrLauncherAppsContainer"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:tag="partOfLauncher">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/llLauncherPinnedApps"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:tag="partOfLauncher">
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llListenerContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llListener"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llShadow"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/launcherservice_shadow"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:tag="shadow">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`llListenerContainer` and its child element `llListener` are what's of importance here. The other two elements are hidden by default and will be shown when a touch on the bottom half of the left edge of the screen is detected.

On the following screenshot I've made `llListener` visible by giving it a red background colour;

[image: Screenshot with llListener made visible]

So touches inside the red area should be handled by my service, but touches on the upper half of the left edge should just be handled by the app underneath it.

Relevant Java code;

```
public class LauncherService extends Service
{
    private WindowManager wm;
    private TouchListener touchListener;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private LinearLayout llListenerContainer;
    private LinearLayout llListener;
    private LinearLayout llLauncher;
    private LinearLayout llShadow;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind (Intent intent)
    { return null; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ()
    {
        super.onCreate ();

        this.wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService (WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService (Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.service_launcher, null, false);

        this.llLauncher = (LinearLayout) this.layout.findViewById (R.id.llLauncher);
        this.llListenerContainer = (LinearLayout) this.layout.findViewById (R.id.llListenerContainer);
        this.llListener = (LinearLayout) this.layout.findViewById (R.id.llListener);
        this.llShadow = (LinearLayout) this.layout.findViewById (R.id.llShadow);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        this.touchListener = new TouchListener (this);

        lalBfb.setOnTouchListener (this.touchListener);
        this.llListener.setOnTouchListener (this.touchListener);
        this.llShadow.setOnTouchListener (this.touchListener);

        this.wm.addView (this.layout, params);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int id)
    {
        this.layout.setVisibility (intent.getBooleanExtra ("show", true) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        return super.onStartCommand (intent, flags, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy ()
    {
        super.onDestroy ();

        this.wm.removeView (this.layout);
    }

    //# Event handlers #//
    public void swipeRight ()
    {
        this.llLauncher.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        this.llShadow.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        this.llListenerContainer.setVisibility (View.GONE);
    }

    public void swipeLeft ()
    {
        this.llLauncher.setVisibility (View.GONE);
        this.llShadow.setVisibility (View.GONE);
        this.llListenerContainer.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    private LauncherService parent;

    public TouchListener (LauncherService parent)
    { this.parent = parent; }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch (View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int id = view.getId ();

        if (id == R.id.llListener)
        {
            this.parent.swipeRight ();

            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.llShadow)
        {
            this.parent.swipeLeft ();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the opportunity to try this on a device yet, but it could be because you are defining the height of your parent layout to "match_parent".

Can you try changing that to "wrap_content" ?